# how to solve this quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

$n^2-4n+2=0$ I have tried many things for this but I cant resolve the roots

here $n$ should be a positive whole number as it stands for time.

Comment: This equation has no solution over the integers.

Comment: By the rational root theorem, the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1,\pm2$. None of these work. (Alternatively, note that this is the same as $(n-2)^2=2$---but you certainly can't square any integers and get 2.)

Comment: why was this downvoted

Answer (score 3):

$$\Delta=(-4)^2-4 \cdot 2=16-8=8$$

$$n_{1,2}=\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2}=\frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{2}}{2}=2 \pm \sqrt{2}$$

So,the roots are $2 + \sqrt{2}$ and $2 - \sqrt{2}$ (both of them are positive).

Answer (score 2):

Using the discriminant
$$\Delta=4^2-4\times 2=8$$
so the roots are
$$n_1=\frac12(4+\sqrt8)\qquad n_2=\frac12(4-\sqrt8)$$
and these two roots are irrational.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ n^2- 4n+2 = 0 \,\Rightarrow\,  (n-2)^2 = 2\,\Rightarrow\,n\,$ irrational